# Tachar una fila o columna con una línea en Latex

Tags: latex

Tengo esta matriz y me gustaría tachar lineas y columnas(sin incluir el nombre de las variables ti y ai , pero no tengo idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}% http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}% Left delimiter
    \renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}% Right delimiter
    \[
    \text{matriz} = \kbordermatrix{
        & t1 & t2 & t3 & t4 & t5 \\
        a1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        a2 & 0 & 1 & 14 & 99 & 0 \\
        a3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        a4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        a5 & 30 & 155 & 0 & 0 & 0
    }
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución rápida, alternativa al [paquete `tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
%\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\[
\text{matriz} = \kbordermatrix{
 & t1 & t2 & t3 & t4 & t5 \\
a1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
a2 & 0 & 1 & 14 & 99 & 0 \\
a3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 %
\makebox(-6,0){\rule[1ex]{.8pt}{14ex}} % vertical
\makebox(-52,2){\rule[1ex]{21ex}{.8pt}} % horizontal
 & 0 \\
a4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
a5 & 30 & 155 & 0 & 0 & 0
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: matriz]

[Referencia 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47730/draw-a-line-through-one-column-of-a-matrix); [referencia 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196258/draw-a-vertical-line-over-the-entries-of-a-column-in-an-array); [referencia 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79741/draw-a-horizonal-line-over-the-entries-of-a-row-in-an-array).

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación del paquete [`kbordermatrix`](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kcborder/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf), no hay ninguna funcionalidad al respecto. Pero ya que usas `ulem` puedes usar el comando `\xout{}` o también puede probar el paquete [`cancel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel) y usar `\cancel{}`. Por ejemplo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}% http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}% Left delimiter
    \renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}% Right delimiter
    \[
    \text{matriz} = \kbordermatrix{
        & t1 & t2 & t3 & t4 & t5 \\
        a1 &  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        a2 & 0 & 1 & 14 & 99 & 0 \\
        a3 & \cancel{0} & \cancel{10} & \cancel{1} & \cancel{0} & \cancel{0} \\
        a4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        a5 & \xout{30} & \xout{155} & \xout{0} & \xout{0} & \xout{0}
    }
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]